# Unable to send email via Postfix SMTP via Mac Mail App

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I installed a SMTP server with Postfix as mail agent (on Ubuntu 12.04). Config is as follow:

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = mail.example.com, example.com, example, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 203.80.250.0/26 192.168.200.0/24 218.213.78.192/26 59.148.211.162/32 10.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

However, weird thing happens when I try to use this SMTP on my Mac, which is in a different network than my server.

When I use Mac OS X (10.10.3)'s Mail App, it said the SMTP cannot be connected. Settings are as follow:

- Mail Server: mail.example.com
- Port: 25
- Authentication: No
- Username & Password: Empty
- Use SSL: No

However, I use `telnet` in Terminal, it works:

```
$telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying 123.123.123.123...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
HELO example.com
250 mail.example.com
MAIL FROM: sender@example.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: example@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
Testing
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E44CC240959
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

The response looks fine to me. What Postfix settings did I miss?

p.s.

1. all domains are replaced with example.com
2. sender@example.com is a created email account in the server
3. there is also Dovecot installed
4. the SMTP server is listening at 0.0.0.0:25

---

**UPDATE** The exact error message in Mail App's Mail Connection Doctor is:

> Could not connect to this SMTP server. Check your network connection and that you entered the correct information in the Account preferences.

--

**UPDATE** And I enabled the logging of Mail App, which brings me this useful log (containing error messages):

```
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 220  (41 additional bytes)
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: Connected: <MFSMTPConnection: 0x7fc3dc4edae0> (Connected) account: A{SMTP - 89AD1B73-5242-45DF-99C3-10B294A5D489}
    hostname: mail.example.com, port: 25, security layer: kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] >> EHLO  (16 additional bytes) 
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-mail.example.com

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-PIPELINING

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-SIZE 10240000

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-VRFY

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-ETRN

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-STARTTLS

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250-8BITMIME

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 250 DSN

Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] >> STARTTLS (0 additional bytes) 
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: [0x7fc3dc4edae0] << 220 2.0.0  (18 additional bytes)
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: Could not connect: <MFSMTPConnection: 0x7fc3dc4edae0> (Disconnected) account: A{SMTP - 89AD1B73-5242-45DF-99C3-10B294A5D489} (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused")
Jun 10 20:23:54 RaptoriMac.local Mail[413] <Debug>: Could not connect: <MFSMTPConnection: 0x7fc3dc4edae0> (Disconnected) account: A{SMTP - 89AD1B73-5242-45DF-99C3-10B294A5D489} (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused")
```

The error message is on the last line right after `STARTTLS` command:

> Could not connect:  (Disconnected) account: A{SMTP - 89AD1B73-5242-45DF-99C3-10B294A5D489} (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused")

How do I solve it? I already marked `allow using insecure connection`, but it still attempts to start TLS connection. I think it attempts to connect at port 465, which is blocked by firewall. Am I correct?

Comment: Any mail.log entry when MailApp connect to postfix?

Comment: Also, what was the exact message from Mail.app? Was there anything in `/var/log/` on the Mac?

Comment: @masegaloeh no. The mail log does not reflect any connection attempt from MailApp to postfix.

Comment: @JennyD posted the exact message, as well as Mail App's log. Can you review it? thanks for help.

Comment: It seems your app is trying to use TLS even though you say you've configured it not to do that, and that's where it fails.

Comment: Probably I need to report bug to Apple.

Comment: It is strongly advised not to configure your service on port 25 for sending services. Look in master.cf and enable the submission service and use port 587 in your client. It's also strongly advised to set up authentication for sending clients -- I don't know exactly why your connection is being dropped, but even if it weren't, you should get a relay denied rejection because the default postfix behavior is to disallow sending as an open relay as you seem to be trying to do here. (When you test via telnet, make sure NOT to do so on the same server.)